# SpaceSaving frequent item counter in Python

Tags: python, algorithm, python-3.x

In the code below, I implemented the SpaceSaving frequency estimation algorithm described in [this paper](http://www.cse.ust.hk/~raywong/comp5331/References/EfficientComputationOfFrequentAndTop-kElementsInDataStreams.pdf). Given a parameter `eps`, the algorithm finds all elements of a data stream of length `n` that occur more than `n/eps` times (with high probability). Here's a screenshot from the paper with the pseudocode:

[image: SpaceSaving algorithm pseudocode]

I would appreciate any feedback on my implementation: style, performance, etc.

```
import math, heapq

class SpaceSavingCounter:
    def __init__(self, eps):
        self.k = math.ceil(1/eps)
        self.n = 0
        self.counts = dict()
        self.queue = []

    def inc(self, x):
        # increment total elements seen
        self.n += 1

        # x is being watched
        if x in self.counts:
            self.counts[x] += 1

        # x is not being watched
        else:
            # make room for x
            if self.n > self.k:
                while True:
                    count, tstamp, key = self.pop()
                    assert self.counts[key] >= count
                    if self.counts[key] == count:
                        del self.counts[key]
                        break
                    else:
                        self.push(self.counts[key], tstamp, key)
            else:
                count = 0

            # watch x
            self.counts[x] = count + 1
            self.push(count, self.n, x)


    def push(self, count, tstamp, key):
        heapq.heappush(
            self.queue,
            (count, tstamp, key)
        )

    def pop(self):
        return heapq.heappop(self.queue)

def test_SpaceSavingCounter():
    seq = [1,5,3,4,2,7,7,1,3,1,3,1,3,1,3]
    counter = SpaceSavingCounter(1 / 1.9)
    for x in seq:
        counter.inc(x)
    assert counter.counts.keys() == {1,3}
```

Comment: It's fine if you're just implementing this for fun/school/practice, but if you're in Python 3+ (based on your tag), why not just use `functools.lru_cache`? It's not identical (and maybe that's the reason), but in many cases it serves the same purpose, and it's built-in (aka, fast and reliable)

Answer (score 3):

Thanks for putting this code online! Two updates for people who may want to use it:

1. Correctness: The "*if self.n > self.k:*" is probably mistaken: for instance, when the sequence starts with k times the same element, we are later stuck with a data structure that contains a single counter. Instead, we can use self.k as representing the number of remaining counters with value 0: specifically, replace this line by "*if self.k==0:*" and just after the "*else:*" insert "*self.k=self.k-1*".
2. Small optimization: above "*def push*", replace by "*self.push(self.counts[x], self.n, x)*", i.e. use the latest value of x since we just updated it

Answer (score 2):

Structure seems pretty good, I'd mainly make the follwing changes:

- Use underscores and more desciptive names for internal variables and functions
- `push` and `pop` look like the would have stack-like behaviour, so I turned them into internal methods with more appropriate names.
- `inc` would better be named and work like `update` from `Counter`, so I changed that and put the logic into the method `_update_element` for each single element.
- I refactored the large if by flattening it out and splitting off the replacement logic.

Also, I made the constructor use the capacity instead of the epsilon, but that's just a matter of preference (a solution supporting both, via keyword arguments, would be in order).

```py
class SpaceSavingCounter:
    """
    Efficient `Counter`-like structure for approximating the top `m` elements of a stream, in O(m)
    space (https://www.cse.ust.hk/~raywong/comp5331/References/EfficientComputationOfFrequentAndTop-kElementsInDataStreams.pdf).

    Specifically, the resulting counter will contain the correct counts for the top k elements with
    k ≈ m.  The interface is the same as `collections.Counter`.
    """

    def __init__(self, m):
        self._m = m
        self._elements_seen = 0
        self._counts = Counter()  # contains the counts for all elements
        self._queue = []  # contains the estimated hits for the counted elements

    def _update_element(self, x):
        self._elements_seen += 1

        if x in self._counts:
            self._counts[x] += 1
        elif len(self._counts) < self._m:
            self._counts[x] = 1
            self._heappush(1, self._elements_seen, x)
        else:
            self._replace_least_element(x)

    def _replace_least_element(self, e):
        while True:
            count, tstamp, key = self._heappop()
            assert self._counts[key] >= count

            if self._counts[key] == count:
                break
            else:
                self._heappush(self._counts[key], tstamp, key)

        del self._counts[key]
        self._counts[e] = count + 1
        self._heappush(count, self._elements_seen, e)

    def _heappush(self, count, tstamp, key):
        heapq.heappush(self._queue, (count, tstamp, key))

    def _heappop(self):
        return heapq.heappop(self._queue)
```

The other thing is that I would expect the interface to be the same as `Counter`.  I have turned your `counts` into `_counts: Counter` anyway, so lets add some methods that just delegate work:

```py
    def most_common(self, n=None):
        return self._counts.most_common(n)

    def elements(self):
        return self._counts.elements()

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self._counts)

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        return self._counts[key]

    def __iter__(self):
        return iter(self._counts)

    def __contains__(self, item):
        return item in self._counts

    def __reversed__(self):
        return reversed(self._counts)

    def items(self):
        return self._counts.items()

    def keys(self):
        return self._counts.keys()

    def values(self):
        return self._counts.values()
```

I left out anything that would modify the values; that seems not necessary for this use case (or is left as an exercise).

Finally, a couple more test cases:

````py
def test_SpaceSavingCounter():
    ssc = SpaceSavingCounter(2)
    ssc.update([1, 5, 3, 4, 2, 7, 7, 1, 3, 1, 3, 1, 3, 1, 3])
    assert ssc.keys() == {1, 3}

    ssc = SpaceSavingCounter(2)
    ssc.update([1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2])
    assert ssc.keys() == {3, 2}

    ssc = SpaceSavingCounter(1)
    ssc.update([1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2])
    assert ssc.keys() == {2}

    ssc = SpaceSavingCounter(3)
    ssc.update([1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2])
    assert ssc.keys() == {1, 2, 3}

    ssc = SpaceSavingCounter(2)
    ssc.update([])
    assert ssc.keys() == set()
```
````